# Installation of Ubuntu on MSI U120 netbook

Tags: system-installation

How and what are the best versions of Ubuntu to install on a MSI U120 netbook? It has a Intel Atom Atom 1.6 Ghz CPU and memory of DDRII 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

The U120 came out in 2009- on a machine with such limited resources, you probably won't want to try running full Ubuntu with Unity, which can be a real resource hog.

That being said, you don't have to settle for an outdated OS. [Give Xubuntu a look:](http://xubuntu.org/) The GTK-based XFCE desktop environment is good on systems with limited resources, and yet pretty and configurable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an even faster and more minimalistic version Lubuntu is your best bet.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu